# (Combinatorics) If there is a 5 x 5 bingo board with one space missing how many permutations are there

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, combinations

Imagine a 5x5 board with one space fixed but can be filled with 500 different things (or a number 1-500) how many combinations can you generate?

Comment: On a regular bingo board (which uses $1$-$75$), the first column can only contain numbers in the range $1$-$15$, the second column $16$-$30$, and so on. Do we have a similar limitation here?

Comment: And does the order of elements within a row or column matter?  If not, the problem becomes more difficult.

Comment: @Arthur there aren't any traditional rules or structure, it is simply a 5 x 5 entity with 500 discrete elements, similar to a scratch off, but with a space fixed so there are 24 squares

Answer (score 0):

There are $5\times5-1=24$ spaces to fill with distinct choices from $500$ things. If the order matters, there are
$$24!\times\binom{500}{24}=\frac{500!}{476!}\approx1.96654\times10^{1110},$$
permutations, which is a really big number. If the order doesn't matter, there are
$$\binom{500}{24}=\frac{500!}{24!476!}
=54827357333432750995708546189537690075500\approx5.48274\times10^{40},$$
combinations, which is a big number, but a lot smaller than the other one.